# How to find and display duplicate integer from an array that stored sum

Tags: c#

I want to display the competitor who has same results for instance, index 3,4,6 of newarray has same sum. In this case I am supposed to display like "Competitor 4, competitor 6, competitor 7 are the highest with score 7".

However my code down below only show competitor 4 are the highest with score 7.

```
int[] newarray = new newarray{4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2, 7}


public static void Compare_competitor(int[] newarray) {

    /// Create a new valiable for highest results.
    int Max_score_of_highest_competitor = newarray[0];

    /// Create a new valiable for finding index of a competitor who is highest.
    int indexofmax = newarray[0];

    /// Use for loop to find out highest competitor from newarray.
    for (int index = 0; index < newarray.Length; index++) {
        if ((Max_score_of_highest_competitor < newarray[index])) {
            /// Exchange values between tmp and Max_score_of_highest_competitor.
            int tmp = Max_score_of_highest_competitor;
            Max_score_of_highest_competitor = newarray[index];
            newarray[index] = Max_score_of_highest_competitor;

            /// This is a index of highest competitor.
            indexofmax = index;
        }                               

    }

    /// Show users a highest competitor with score.    
    Console.WriteLine("\nAnd the winner is competitor{0}", indexofmax + 1);
    Console.WriteLine("with total scores of {0}", Max_score_of_highest_competitor);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling method `Compare_competitor` ?

Comment: There are other methods above this method so I call this method above.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be  "Competitor 4, competitor 5, competitor 7", have you posted it wrong or have I misunderstood it?

Comment: yeah sorry your correct 4,5,7

Comment: Indexes starts at zero so the correct indexes are 3,4 and 6

Comment: @Steve he wrote the indexes right but the output should be "Competitor index+1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a LINQ solution in the `Compare_competitor` method :

```
public static void Compare_competitor(int[] newarray)
{
    var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, newarray.Length)
                            .Where(i => newarray[i] == newarray.Max())
                            .Select(i => i);

    List<string> winners = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in indexes)
    {
        winners.Add(String.Format("Competitor {0}", item + 1));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} are the highest with score of {1}", 
                      string.Join(", ", winners), newarray.Max());
}
```

`Enumerable.Range(0, newarray.Length)` generates a sequence of integer numbers within a specified range, in your case from `0` to `newarray.Length-1` (`0,1,2..6`). This sequence represent the indexes of the array elements. The `Where` clause filters the indexes of the elements that are equale to the highest element in `newarray` (`newarray.Max()`).The `Select` clause then stores these indexes in the variable `indexes`.

Method call:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr = { 4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2, 7 };
    Compare_competitor(arr);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output** : Competitor 4, Competitor 5, Competitor 7 are the highest with score of 7

[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RDNiSM)

Comment: @SouichiKitai I updated my post with an explanation of how my code works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] newarray = new int[] { 4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2, 7 };
    Console.WriteLine(Compare_competitor(newarray));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string Compare_competitor(int[] newarray)
{
    string message = "";
    //find max. value, then iterate through array and add "Competitor" + index to the message, if has max. score
    int max = newarray.Max();
    for(int i = 0; i < newarray.Length; i++)
        message += newarray[i] == max ? "Competitor " + (i + 1) + ", " : "";
    //remove last comma and space from current string
    message = message.Remove(message.Length - 2);
    return message + " are the highest with score " + max;
}
```

Comment: @SouichiKitai Accept the answer if it helped (and upvote if you like).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
int[] newarray = new int[] { 4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2, 7 };
public static void Compare_competitor(int[] newarray)
    {
        List<int> highestScorers = new List<int>();

        int Max_score_of_highest_competitor = newarray.Max(); //Getting Max value from newarray

        /// Use for loop to find out highest competitor from newarray.

        for (int index = 0; index < newarray.Length; index++)
        {
            if (Max_score_of_highest_competitor == newarray[index])
            {
                highestScorers.Add(index);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nAnd the winner's are:");

        /// Show users a highest competitor with score.

        for (int i = 0; i < highestScorers.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Competitor: {0}", highestScorers[i]);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("with total scores of {0}", Max_score_of_highest_competitor);

    }
```

Comment: @SouichiKitai i am very glad that i could help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] newarray = new[] { 4, 6, 2, 7, 7, 2, 7 };

var highest = newarray.Select((x, n) => new { x, n }).GroupBy(x => x.x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).First();

var result = String.Join(", ", highest.Select(h => $"Competitor {h.n + 1}")) + $" are the highest with {highest.Key}";
```

That gives:

> Competitor 4, Competitor 5, Competitor 7 are the highest with 7